# THREE.FileLoader is not a constructor(…)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a model into my scene.

I've included these files at the top of my project:

```
     <script src="js/build/three.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
```

This is my code

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load( "res/rose/ModelsAndTextures/rose.obj", function ( object ) {
      scene.add( object );
    } );
```

**But I get error: OBJLoader.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: THREE.FileLoader is not a constructor(…)**

I looked in the OBJLoader.js file and to find THREE.FileLoader - this is the line the error is on:

```
           var loader = new THREE.FileLoader( scope.manager );
```

Other peoples examples of this work fine

Comment: what revision of `Three.js`?

Comment: I just downloaded three.min.js from github today, so should be the latest

Comment: i also tried with the main three.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out if you're using the [right OBJLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cf584a60bdfd24c42eaa81d484533364742bda44/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js).

Take a look at an example that shows how to use this object properly:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer, camera, banana;

var ww = window.innerWidth,
  wh = window.innerHeight;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.getElementById('scene')
});
renderer.setSize(ww, wh);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, ww / wh, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);
scene.add(camera);

//Add a light in the scene
directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 350);
directionalLight.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
scene.add(directionalLight);

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  banana.rotation.z += .01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

var loadOBJ = function() {
  //Manager from ThreeJs to track a loader and its status
  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  //Loader for Obj from Three.js
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);

  //Launch loading of the obj file, addBananaInScene is the callback when it's ready 
  loader.load('http://mamboleoo.be/learnThree/demos/banana.obj', function(object) {
    banana = object;
    //Move the banana in the scene
    banana.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    banana.position.y = -200;
    banana.position.z = 50;
    //Go through all children of the loaded object and search for a Mesh
    object.traverse(function(child) {
      //This allow us to check if the children is an instance of the Mesh constructor
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material.color = new THREE.Color(0X00FF00);
        //Sometimes there are some vertex normals missing in the .obj files, ThreeJs will compute them
        child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
      }
    });
    
    scene.add(banana);
    render();
  });
};

loadOBJ();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mamboleoo.be/learnThree/demos/OBJLoader.js"></script>

<canvas id="scene"></canvas>
```

Comment: Passing `LoadingManager` as a pararmeter to `ObjLoader` is not necessary.

Comment: Its working, but im still getting error - OBJLoader.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: onLoad is not a function(…)

Comment: I am using the same include as you, maboleoo one

Comment: Also how do I scale my object once loaded? Im trying: myObject.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1); But the object is the same size?

Comment: I tried putting the object into a new Mesh, scaling that, then adding it - but that also doesn't work

Comment: dear god these comments are a mess ANYWAY, TLDR USE THIS:   var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  loader.load( "res/rose/ModelsAndTextures/rose.obj", function ( object ) {
  object.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    scene.add( object );
  } );

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle with your current code and update your question with the new insights? It's be a better idea if you create a new question... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and realized I used an old version of the three.js file. I replaced it with the three.js in the build folder of the three.js download where I took the OBJLoader from.